# PHP.ini Directory Problems

Tags: php

I am using a php5.ini file to set up and include path so I can call a "main.php" file from any directory.  The problem I ran into is that when I set up multiple sites on my server, I wanted each site to be able to include its own "main.php" file from its own directory aslong as the file was in each sites root folder.  When I researched ini files, I found that there can only be one ini files on the server.  So my real question is, how can I either created separate ini files for separate directories or set up a way to include files from separate directories from one php.ini files?  Here is what code I am using now:

`include_path = .:/html/WEBSITE1/lib:/html/WEBSITE2/lib:/`

So if I create a PHP file in /html/WEBSITE1/, I want it only to include files from /html/WEBSITE1/lib and the same thing for WEBSITE2.

Comment: There are many ways to step on your eggs, and U did it! Set up include path for every site separatly. Or use MVC where setup path will be centralized. Using php.ini for all sites is bad idea.

Comment: I guess colons work too...  They have so far lol.  I might just set it in each htaccess file.

Comment: Try set up in htaccess php_value include_path ".:/usr/www/your_user_folder/your_website_folder/includes" with full path - it's rewrite whole include path